# Proving a relation between $\sum\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I ran into this question:

> Prove that:
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}=\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 16):

Hint: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Comment: @user76508 No problem, I am loyal to the Workers.

Comment: @RobFord I thought you were libertarian?

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

$$n\in\Bbb N:=\{1,2,\ldots\}:\;\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}=\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}\ldots$$

Comment: I simply not understanding how the right and left side are equal of the series.

Comment: please help me to understand.

Comment: @Tsotsi: just divide the sum of the reciprocals of the squared naturals in even ones $\,(2n)^{-2}\,$ and odd ones $\,(2n-1)^{-2}\,$ , but then $\,(2n)^{-2}=2^{-2}\cdot n^{-2}\,$ and etc.

Comment: $1^2+{1\over 2^2}+{1\over 3^2}+\dots+{1\over n^2}+\dots={1\over (2n)^2}+{1\over (2n-1)^2}+\dots$ am I right?

Comment: @DonAntonio I should be hanged :(